# If account is disabled while logged in can it remain logged in?

Tags: active-directory, service-accounts

We have an account that connects in via VPN to pull data from one of our databases.  Recently it has not been able to pull the data down.

Looking at it the account is disabled however I feel that this is not the full story.

```
Enabled                            : False    
LastLogonDate                      : 09/05/2011 11:06:21
lastLogonTimestamp                 : 129494091812160209
LockedOut                          : False
Modified                           : 30/01/2012 11:22:41
modifyTimeStamp                    : 30/01/2012 11:22:41
whenChanged                        : 30/01/2012 11:22:41
whenCreated                        : 18/07/2008 16:45:39
```

So the last time it was modified was the 30th Jan 2012 yet its last login is the 9th May.  Considering that disabling an account updates the modified date does anyone have any suggestion as to how this could come about?  Am a touch concerned that something untoward is going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disabling an account wont log a disabled user out, it will just stop them logging in.

Oh, you didnt notice the last login was May 2011..? (A year ago)

Comment: [slams head in to desk]  Cannot see the wood for the trees.  Time for a coffee or something.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the year.  It has not logged on since it was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The account was modified after it was disabled. This can happen for a variety of reason. Disabled accounts can still be changed.

And of course, you will not be able to pull down data with a disabled account.